# A link that displays a pdf which is stored on database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have pdf stored on database as binary. I want links that display them when they have been clicked. I used entity-framework code-first and mvc with c#. If someone know how it works so please tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share what have you did so far? Any error?

Answer (score 0):

If your file is stored as byte[] you can simply return a FileResult in your controller method using:

```
public ActionResult DownloadPDF(int id) 
{
    byte[] pdffile = [your file];
    return File(pdffile, "application/pdf");
}
```

For detailed Information on File method please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an action in any of your controllers which can pick the binary coded pdf from the database and serve it upon request. For example:

```cs
class PDFController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Download(int id)
  {
    byte[] fileContents;
    // Your code to read the binary file from DB.
    // fileContents = // Populate from DB

    return new FileContentResult(fileContents, "application/pdf");
  }

}
```

Now add a link to this action say (`/pdf/download/1`)